# Problem with Verdana when embedding as resource in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts

I'm usually creating 1 .as file per font and exports these .as files to swf's that I load in to my flash projects. This way I can choose what characters to embed.

Now I tested copying my verdana ttf fontfiles from my Windows font folder and embedded this to create a Verdana swf fontfile.

When I tested running this I tried with some swedish characters with dots (åäö ÅÄÖ). The dots above the characters from some of these charcters was positioned slightly offset (like a few pixels to the right or left). Anyone had the same problem?

Example code:

```
[Embed(source = 'fontfiles/verdana.ttf', fontName = 'Verdana', mimeType="application/x-font-truetype", unicodeRange = 'U+00-U+FF')]  
public static var font:Class;  

public function Verdana()
{
    Font.registerFont(font);
    var tf:TextField = new TextField();
    tf.embedFonts = true;
    tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    tf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("Verdana", 30);
    tf.text = "abc åäö ÅÄÖ";
    addChild(tf);
}
```

Comment: If the dots display, but are offset, to be honest that sounds like it could be a bug. Can you edit in what version of authoring/player you're using? If you can, you might try exporting with a different OS, version of Flash, or version of Verdana - if it's a bug, I have a feeling one of those changes will make it stop reproducing. (Especially the font - I hear sometimes of issues where a font seems fine, but Flash thinks something about it is corrupted.)

Comment: Yeah, seems like some kind of bug.

I'm using Flash Develop compiling with Flex SDK 3.4. Using Windows 7 and I also tried copying the Verdana font from previous Windows installations with the same problem.

But I think I found a solution, I changed:
source = 'fontfiles/verdana.ttf'
to
systemFont = 'Verdana'

And this seems to work. Will need to test a bit more to make sure this doesn't generate any other problems. But thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed:

```
[Embed(source = 'fontfiles/verdana.ttf', fontName = 'Verdana', mimeType="application/x-font-truetype", unicodeRange = 'U+00-U+FF')]  
public static var font:Class;
```

To:

```
[Embed(systemFont = 'Verdana', fontName = 'Verdana', mimeType="application/x-font-truetype", unicodeRange = 'U+00-U+FF')]  
public static var font:Class;
```

Seems like this did make it work.